# What will happen with my RAID5 after motherboard change?

Tags: motherboard, raid, software-raid, raid-5

Currently I have `ASUS P5Q-EM` and 3 HDDs in RAID5 using its on-board RAID controller `Intel ICH10R`.

I want to buy new motherboard, for example, `Gigabyte GA-EQ45M-S2` which also has on-board RAID controller but `Intel ICH10DO`.

What will happen with my data on RAID5? Will I have to re-create the array from the scratch and lost all my data?

Is such array a soft RAID or soft-hard? What if my current motherboard will break one day? What will happen with my data?

Comment: So how did it go?

Comment: @torbengb: I didn't buy new mb. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is fake hardware RAID. It's not software RAID in the sense that it's RAID from inside the OS (which would actually be more portable) and it's certainly not hardware RAID in the sense that it doesn't have a dedicated XOR processor or a physically separate controller card.

Since both are ICH10 variations, you MAY be able to boot it if you reconstruct the array in the RAID BIOS, but don't reinitialize it. Make sure you have a good backup before doing this.